# CSS Image Arrow overlap

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I've gotten a design from a designer with a seemingly simple feature, but when building it, it turns out to be not that simple...
I've found many ways to create a CSS3 arrow, which is exactly what I need, but it needs to have the image as fill color in order to overlap the underlying div.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see the image overlaps the next section. The most tricky part is that this is part of an image slider. Which means I can not just cut the arrow in the image because the image will slide. So I need some kind of overlay I guess?

The slider in use is [Whoothemes' flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) at 100% width.

I hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: You could use clip path to make this.

Comment: Which part is the problem? Creating the little triangle, or getting it to overlap the next div?

Comment: It would be nice to know, if you could solve your problem and if my answer was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should add two elements (likely :before and :after) to that images parent item.

```
.arrow-down
{
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
}

.arrow-down:after,
.arrow-down:before
{
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    background-color: transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
}
/* left part */
.arrow-down:before
{
    left: 0;
    right: 50%; 
    bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 38px solid red;
    border-left: 0 none hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
    border-right: 60px inset hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
}

/*right part*/
.arrow-down:after
{
    right: 0;
    left: 50%; 
    bottom: 0px;
    border-bottom: 38px solid red;
    border-right: 0 none hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
    border-left: 60px inset hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);
}
```

See it in action: http://fiddle.jshell.net/usz62/
sure needs some tuning.